# How to play a section of a youtube video on a loop?

Tags: youtube

I am trying to make a youtube video loop at a specific section of a video.

https://www.youtube.com/v/zeI-JD6RO0k?autoplay=1&loop=1&start=30&end=33&playlist=%20zeI-JD6RO0k

From what I know:

To start and end:

```
start=30&end=33
```

To make it loop:

```
autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=%20zeI-JD6RO0
```

The problem is that it doesn't start the next loop at the time I specify

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Youtube Iframe-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to loop a video section.

Place this tag in your HTML-page:

```html
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>
```

Load Youtube Iframe-API

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Create player and loop video:

```js
var section = {
  start: 30,
  end: 33
};

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player(
    'player',
    {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'zeI-JD6RO0k',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    }
  );
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player.seekTo(section.start);
  player.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    var duration = section.end - section.start;
    setTimeout(restartVideoSection, duration * 1000);
  }
}

function restartVideoSection() {
  player.seekTo(section.start);
}
```

[See this example in action](http://jsbin.com/ropixuyona/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

Note first, if one is not familiar with html or javascript beyond basics, the youtube player api link in the answer by maiermic will provide everything necessary to develop the solution provided there -on one page without a lot of skimming.

also, in case one would like to add a hh:mm:ss converter that accepts down to seconds - add / modify the code provided in the answer by maiermic with the following;

```
var timeStart = "HH:MM:SS";
var timeEnd = "HH:MM:SS";

var loopStart = getSeconds(timeStart);
var loopEnd =  getSeconds(timeEnd);

var section = {
  start: loopStart,
  end: loopEnd
};
```

and add the function;

```
function getSeconds(str) {
    var p = str.split(':'),
    s = 0, m = 1;

    while (p.length > 0) {
        s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
        m *= 60;
    }

    return s;
}
```

And in the case one would like to include slower playback up to normal speed with this code, alter the following function with

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        var duration;

        var playerSpeed = player.getPlaybackRate();

        if (playerSpeed == .25)
            duration = (section.end - section.start) * 4;
        else if (playerSpeed == .5) 
            duration = (section.end - section.start) * 2;
        else if (playerSpeed == .75) 
            duration = (section.end - section.start) * 1.5;
        else if (playerSpeed == 1) 
            duration = (section.end - section.start);

        setTimeout(restartVideoSection, duration * 1000);
    }
  }
```

as well as

```
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.seekTo(section.start);
        player.setPlaybackRate(.25);     // choose .25, .50, .75, or 1
        player.playVideo();
    }
```

Of course, you will have to modify the video id/ HH:MM:SS fields in the code every time you want a different video / section of video. Additionally, if one chooses to include support for variable player speed as above, those values will have to be added as desired. The playback speed can be altered via the player buttons once started if the code above is included, but if it is changed during play back, the duration will not refresh until the video begins at the start again.